# why can not start zabbix-server with postgresql and ngnix in my ubuntu

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, zabbix, systemctl

i installed zabbix 6 and postgresql 14.4 and ngnix and zabbix agent in ubuntu 20.04. when i want to start zabbix on ubunu with `systemctl start zabbix-server` and get following message:

```
Job for zabbix-server.service failed because the service did not take
the steps required by its unit configuration.
```

how I can run zabbix-server in my ubuntu?

Comment: You are going to want to check the logs for details of why. Start with `systemctl status zabbix-server` and `journalctl -u zabbix-server` and check recently updated files in /var/log